# Tips on debugging copy and paste into PowerPoint 2010

Tags: c++, powerpoint, copy-paste

I have a custom application in C++ that has been used to successfully copy-and-paste an object from the application into MS Office 2003 and 2007 (Word, Excel and PowerPoint). The object opens in our own custom ActiveX control.

Now with Windows XP and PowerPoint 2010, nothing happens on the cut-and-paste. I have tried turning off the smart copy/paste to no avail. Copy/paste works with Word and Excel 2010.

Do you have tips on how to debug this?

Comment: just wanted to follow up to see if the below answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just pasting to PowerPoint or are you pasting to an object in PowerPoint? Word and Excel differ in that there is *always* a selection object (the cursor) - but PowerPoint doesn't have one unless you specifically specify one (if you do this manually, PowerPoint itself will create an object if nothing is selected)